# Why can a static method change a class object's attributes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class below with a static method that takes an instance of the Patient class, changes its "id" attribute to a randomly generated number, then puts it in a list if it didn't already exist.

```
class Patient:
    patient_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.place = None
        self.id = 0

    @staticmethod
    def admit_patient(patient): 
        id_generator = random.randint(10000000, 99999999)
        patient.id = id_generator
        print("Assigned UID: " + str(patient.id))
        if any(saved_patient.id == patient.id for saved_patient in Patient.patient_list):
            print("Patient already exists.")
        else:
            print("Patient information saved.")
            Patient.patient_list.append(patient)


new_patient = Patient(input("What is the patient's first & last name? "), input("What is their age? "))
new_patient.admit_patient(new_patient)
```

This same static method works as a regular method, but Python suggested it might be static. I'm confused because I thought static methods weren't tied to any class instances and therefore couldn't modify its states. That doesn't appear to be the case.

It also works as a top-level function but I'm not sure which is best. Did I just get lucky and it works by chance or am I missing something? Thanks for your time.

Comment: A static method doesn't have an instance, correct.  But, you're passing one in when you call `new_patient.admit_patient(new_patient)`.

Comment: "I thought static methods weren't tied to any class instances and therefore couldn't modify its states." well sure, but you are explicitly passing in an instance. staticmethods have no *implicit* access to the instance state, but if I do `my_instance.static_method(my_instance)` then I am *explicitly* giving it access to the state

Comment: Note, from a design POV, `admit_patient` should probably be a `classmethod`, which would function as an alternative constructor, where you generate the id, instantiate a new patient with the id, add it to the patient list, then `return patient`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the difference between a "self instance" and a regular instance.

In a normal method, you have to specify the self argument:

```
class Foo1:
    def bar(*args):
        print(args)

foo1 = Foo1()
foo1.bar() # outputs (<__main__.Foo1 object at 0x0000018EBF7E0608>,)
```

That means that inside the `Bar` method, you have a "self instance" of `Foo`.

What the `staticmethod` decorator does, is it takes the `foo.bar` call, and strips off the `self` argument:

```
class Foo2:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(*args):
        print args

foo2 = Foo2()
foo2.bar() # outputs ()
```

So, if you pass in a `Foo` object, it'll look like this:

```
foo.bar(foo) # outputs (<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000018EBF7E0688>,)
```

This is what you're doing when you call `new_patient.admit_patient(new_patient)`.

Note that this is a non-pythonic way of using a `staticmethod`.  Usually, you would use them *before* you have an instance of the class, calling it on the class itself:

```
Foo2.bar() # outputs ()
```

Whereas, trying to do that with a standard method would normally raise an error as it expects a `self` argument:

```
Foo1.bar() # outputs ()
```

The other useful decorator is `classmethod`, which passes in a class object:

```
class Foo3:
    @classmethod
    def bar(*args):
        print(args)

Foo3.bar() # outputs (<class '__main__.Foo3'>,)
```

Note that it's a `class` rather than an *instance*.